# How to use add_action inside files included by theme's functions.php

Tags: actions

I've a functions.php inside my theme folder. The first line of `functions.php` is

```
require_once 'custom.php';
```

inside `custom.php` I have this simple code:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_js_vars');
function add_js_vars(){ 
    //some stuff here
}
```

The problem with the code above is that add_js_vars is not executed. If I move     `add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_js_vars');` 
inside themes `functions.php`
everything works fine.
I'm not able to understand what's the problem. Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't give any advice without any code.  Please copy and paste your code somewhere http://pastebin.com preferably.

Comment: No, please post it here in case the pastebin link expires. @cardy_web And **please** use code formatting. We take the time to read and maybe answer and you take the time to make this worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap you `include`(s) in a function and hook it to `after_setup_theme` hook.